# Get incremental values from cumulative column in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with Date in yyyymmdd text format and cumulative demand. I want to calculate incremental demand (difference between the current and previous date).

Edit: I cannot change the format of the filedate column as it is used in a lot of other calculations.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a calculated column that finds the previous date and then take the difference of your current value with the value at the previous date.

```
IncrDemand = 
    VAR PrevDate = CALCULATE(LASTDATE(Demand[filedate]),
                       ALL(Demand),
                       Demand[filedate] < EARLIER(Demand[filedate]))
    RETURN Demand[CurModDem] - LOOKUPVALUE(Demand[CurModDem], Demand[filedate], PrevDate)
```

(Assuming your table name is `Demand`.)

Comment: I got this error `A column specified in the call to function 'LASTDATE' is not of type DATE. This is not supported.` Which is actually the problem I am having. This filedate column is used in many other calculations and I cannot change its data type. In one attempt, I converted the column to date (in VAR calulation), subtracted 7 days from it, but I could not convert this back to yyyymmdd format for using it in the Return function. I though there might be a easier way.

Comment: Try replacing `LASTDATE(...)` with `MAX(...)` or `LASTNONBLANK(...,1)`.